# Make Hibernate discriminator value use bind variable instead of literal

Tags: java, sql, oracle, hibernate, jpa

When using the @DiscriminatorColumn on a class and @DiscriminatorValue on subclasses, the SQL that Hibernate generates uses the discriminator value as a literal for the clause involving the discriminator column.

Example:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "PART_TYPE")
@Table(name = "NAME")
public class NamePartEntity implements Comparable<NamePartEntity> {
  // Stuff
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue(value = "GIV")
public class GivenNameEntity extends NamePartEntity {
  // stuff
}
```

If I create a simple criteria query with no criteria except the class, I would get SQL generated like such:

```
select this_.person_id as y0_ from name this_ where this_.part_type='GIV'
```

This isn't so bad until you have a handful of discriminator values and the table might be selected from multiple times, such that a query like the below:

```
SELECT this_.person_id AS y0_
FROM name this_
WHERE this_.part_type='FAM'
AND this_.value_u    =:8
AND this_.tenant_id  =:9
AND this_.person_id IN
  (SELECT this_.person_id AS y0_
  FROM name this_
  WHERE this_.part_type='GIV'
  AND this_.value_u    =:10
  AND this_.tenant_id  =:11
  AND this_.person_id IN
    (SELECT this_.person_id AS y0_
    FROM name this_
    WHERE this_.part_type='GIV'
    AND this_.value_u    =:12
    AND this_.tenant_id  =:13
    AND this_.person_id IN
      (SELECT this_.person_id AS y0_
      FROM name this_
      WHERE this_.part_type='PFX'
      AND this_.value_u    =:14
      AND this_.tenant_id  =:15
      )
    )
  )
```

could have a ton of different SQL ids and execution plans based on the literals ('FAM', 'GIV', 'PFX' in this case but they could be different and in different orders). However, if bind variables were used in place of those discriminator value literals, it would be the same sql id and have the same execution plan.

So, is it possible to have Hibernate use the discriminator column/value annotations in such a way that bind variables are used instead of literals? I know it would be possible to rewrite my entities in such a way to avoid this but I wanted to see if I could get the bind variable functionality with the existing annotations in some way.

Alternatively, is there a way I can still use my extended classes without using discriminator values? If I try that and have the @Entity annotation on each extended class, it complains about missing the discriminator type even when there are no discriminator annotations.

Comment: Is this all generated (dynamic) SQL?  If not then you can set cursor_sharing=FORCE to convert all literals to system binds.

Comment: While cursor_sharing=FORCE will work if this is Oracle, that is generally discouraged. Think twice before implementing it in production!

Comment: @sandman These are dynamic queries and while this is Oracle we are going to be moving off it anyway. However, thanks for the input as someone might find that useful.

Comment: user2612030 wrong on both counts.  FORCE won't work if it's dynamic SQL.  Also, FORCE has been recommended on OLTP since 11g. Oracle’s summary from metalink 1169017.1: “Our recommendation is to set cursor_sharing = FORCE. This setting maximizes cursor sharing while leveraging the Adaptive Cursor Sharing framework to generate multiple execution plans based on different literal value ranges if necessary.”

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible to get it out of the box.

The closest workaround that comes to my mind is to select from the base class and explicitly filter by subclass:

```
entityManager.createQuery("select gne from NamePartEntity gne where type(gne) = :subclass")
    .setParameter("subclass", GivenNameEntity.class)
    .getResultList();
```

Answer (score 0):

> Alternatively, is there a way I can still use my extended classes
>   without using discriminator values? If I try that and have the @Entity
>   annotation on each extended class, it complains about missing the
>   discriminator type even when there are no discriminator annotations

That is because of the `InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE` strategy you've used. You could always try to use other strategies, like `InheritanceType.JOINED`,  depending upon what you query for most often.

On another note, Doesn't having this many types of `Names` per-se an indicator that you must have types as a relation and not a Sub-type?

Comment: Well, JOINED wouldn't work since it's all on one table, no? Every entity has the same part type, just different values. The JOINED strategy seems like it would be for when different fields exist between the entities. 

As for the second comment, I would think Hibernate would control that since it's responsible for generating the SQL. I currently never have to specify the part type since I just use the entity. Of course, I could simply just have NamePartEntity and set the part type but I preferred having the different entities for use when writing Java code.

Comment: Yes, if its going to be on the same table then `JOINED` wouldn't help you. But, if its just a single column then it would roughly translate into a property which could be made a `type` property of `NamePartEntity` . As you say you could have different `classes` in Java (you wish purely), if each `NamePartEntity` behaves considerably different from the other, but they wouldn't have to be `entities` (state info), they could just be `classes` (OO constructs). Just a suggestion as I don't really have the answer you're looking for :)